# How to disable lazy loading on specific environment [React]

Tags: reactjs, webpack, lazy-loading, code-splitting

i am working on a React project , previously i implemented code splitting on this project with React.Lazy feature on navigation routes. Currently it is hard to debug on this chunk files. I need to disable this lazy load on dev env so we can debug on source-map again. Is there anyway that React.lazy load like normal import statement ?

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you should refer to [Environment Variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables) from React docs, and use something like

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
// code or components with lazy loads
} else {
// no lazy loads for debugging 
}
```

Comment: this was my first approach ,it actually works but we have good amount of navigation and pages , i am looking for more generic solution , i also tried to write a function to handle all of this conditional stuff but it didn't work.